# What is numpy.mgrid, technically?

Tags: python, numpy

I have been using `numpy.mgrid` for a while and I am familiar with what it does. But ever since, I have been wondering what it actually is...

A typical use case and syntax for `mgrid` would be

```
xx, yy = mgrid[0:5, 0:3]
```

What bothers me is the syntax `mgrid[...]`, which makes me believe that `mgrid` is not a function or a method. The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) say that `mgrid` is a

> nd_grid instance which returns a dense multi-dimensional “meshgrid”.

What does it do in the background? And why is it used like a function, but the syntax differs from that of a function (I would expect something like `mgrid((0,5), (0,3))`). I am really lost at trying to understand what `mgrid` is.

Any insights are welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`numpy.mgrid` is an *object* of the [`MGridClass`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L209-L254) in `numpy/index_tricks.py`. This object allows you to construct multi-dimensional meshgrids, as you already know.

`MGridClass` extends the [`nd_grid` class](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L109), which implements a [`__getitem__`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L147-L206) method. The square braces actually delegates a call to `nd_grid.__getitem__`, which implements the core logic for constructing the meshgrid based on the slices passed.

A brief MCVE of the working of `nd_grid` can be found here.

```
class dummy_1d_grid:
    def __getitem__(self, val):
        print(val)
        return np.arange(val.start, val.stop, val.step, )
```

```
mgrid_1d = dummy_1d_grid()
mgrid_1d[:5]

slice(0, 5, None)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

np.mgrid[0:5]
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Of course, this is all an implementation detail, so the layout and classes are all subject to change. The point to focus on is that it is an instance of a class implementing the `__getitem__` method. Hence it is sliced, not called.

Comment: That said, knowing the type isn't actually very useful. What matters is the behavior, and knowing the type adds very little. It wouldn't matter if the NumPy developers changed it to a completely different type as long as they kept the documented behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 Correct. The crux of my answer here is that it is an instance of a class that implements `__getitem__`, hence it is _sliced_, and not _called_. I hoped OP would get a better understanding of this if I shared the link to the source.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks, this makes all perfect sense to me, but I have always been wondering  whether this `__getitem__` syntax is not *un-pythonic*, meaning that it is kind of unique among most things in python that I have seen so far? Why was it chosen over a function call?

Comment: @mommermi in a nutshell, slicing syntax can be specified quite naturally if you make a `__getitem__` call as opposed to a function call. You would not be able to do `mgrid(50:100:5)` if `mgrid` was a function... you would have to do `mgrid(slice(50, 100, 5))` which is  a lot more clunky than just `mgrid[50:100:5]`.

Comment: I agree. So efficiency was chosen over consistency.

Comment: @mommermi and, don't forget readability. I feel like the latter is easier to understand. `:` is more natural for specifying slicing as opposed to using the `slice` object directly.

Comment: `meshgrid` is the function equivalent, more or less.